# Display HTML Code in JSP (Don't "render" HTML)

Tags: html, jsp

I have a JSP page which accepts SQL queries, performs them then returns the results in a table. A few of the results occasionally have HTML tags in them i.e. - a result will return:

`This is the returned result! I have <br> and <hr> tags!`

When this gets put through the code to handle the return and place it into a table it will actually "render" the `<br>` and `<hr>` tags as HTML, but I want it to simply show the actual `<br>` and `<hr>` tags.

Currently the return is printed using <%=colvalue %>

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this page for a simple method which will escape a string you pass into it: 
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0306.html

Answer (score 6):

If you're using JSTL, the `<c:out>` tag escapes what you pass to it by default.

E.g.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:out value="${value}"/>
```

You can also use the `escapeXml` el function from the functions taglib

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"  %>
 ${fn:escapeXml(someVarWithHtmlInIt)}
```

Answer (score 1):

`I have &lt;br&gt; and &lt;hr&gt; tags!`

Comment: This will suffer the same problem in getting "rendered" as the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSTL  tag. It has an escapeXML parameter that will do what you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

In PHP you would use [htmlentities](http://us.php.net/htmlentities) and [htmlspecialchars](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)